# Using jQuery, window.resize Event is not triggered?

Tags: jquery, resize, window

GOAL: dynamically change height of each division element so that opposing elements in adjacent columns align horizontally -- like UL LI LI, but without the actual list.

If the window is super wide, each item may only have 1 line; but with window shrinkage, each item may have a unique line count; e.g.

```
item 1      item 2
  1 line      2 lines

item 3       item 4
  3 lines      1 line
```

My desired result is to adjust all items to 3 lines tall via

```
$(window).on('resize', function() { ...});
```

However, this window.resize Event is not triggered?

WHY?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="column extraPaddingOnRight">
<a href="links/headstone.pdf">Nancy at Arlington National Cemetery</a><p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- other DIV links follow -->
```

The CSS:

```
.extraPaddingOnRight {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    /* Theoretically 50%, but less because of extraPaddingOnRight */
    width: 40%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function resizer() {
        var $maxItemHeight = 0, $thisItemHeight;

        $('div.column a').each(function() {
            $thisItemHeight = $(this).height();
            if ($thisItemHeight > $maxItemHeight)
                $maxItemHeight = $thisItemHeight;
        });

        $('div.column a').each(function() {
            $(this).css( {
                height: $maxItemHeight + 'px';
            }); 
        });
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
    /*
        alert('ok');   // not triggered?
    */
        resizer;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a simple syntax error at the line

```
height: $maxItemHeight + 'px';
```

remove the `;`, that is not allowed in an object definition and the error should be visible in the browser console when loading the page.

Also to call your resizer function use `resizer();` or simply `$(window).on('resize', resizer);`

Complete working example, you may need to change the path to your jQuery script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

    function resizer() {
        var $maxItemHeight = 0, $thisItemHeight;

        $('div.column a').each(function() {
            $thisItemHeight = $(this).height();
            if ($thisItemHeight > $maxItemHeight)
                $maxItemHeight = $thisItemHeight;
        });

        $('div.column a').each(function() {
            $(this).css( {
                height: $maxItemHeight + 'px'
            }); 
        });
    }

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        alert('ok');   // not triggered?

        // resizer;
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="testid">foo</div>
<button id="btnTest">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Removed semicolon and called the resizer function as you specified ... unfortunately, no change. A call to alert inside resizer did not happen.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked, at least alert ist popping up. I edit my answer to add a complete working example for your.

Comment: Also tried: $(this).attr("style", "height: $maxItemHeight");

Comment: But first things first, is your resize callback working now? I can see the alert.

Comment: i eliminated having to use on resize by returning to display: table and table-cell for ul and li. Yes, it does work, but I feel "dirty" because it's like writing TABLE, TR etc again!!

Comment: Between your semi-colon and my gigantic html markup error, problem is SOLVED!!  Bunches of "Thank You"

Answer (score 0):

Here was my problem ... took too many stupid pills ...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizer();
    });

 /*
    $(window).on('resize', function() {   // does not work!
        resizer();
    });
 */

 /*
    $(window).on('resize', resizer);       // does not work either! 
 */

})
```

Together with the suggested removal of the semi-colon coupled with a very very dumb error with my HTML Markup ...